# style div with background color in hsl with js calculated luminescence value based on rating

Tags: javascript, hsl

I belong to a chess club with players who have ratings ranging from 0 to 2500
I want to style each screen tuple with an hsl value similar to:
hsl(189, 100%, XX%);  // where XX = player rating / 25

// GET TUPLE DIV ID:

```
var pirate = document.getElementById( 'BOX_' +id_num); //OK it works
```

// GET RATING:

```
rating_rank = document.getElementById("Y" +id_num); // PLAYER RATING
```

// THE MATH DOESN'T WORK // example: player rating = 1500, then rating_factor: 1500 / 25 ===> 60

```
rating_factor = (parseINT(rating_rank) / 25).toString() +"%"; // this line is the culprit, I think

function get_random_color() {
    pirate.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(189, 100%,' + rating_factor +')'; // THIS DW!
    pirate.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(189, 100%, 60%)'; // THIS WORKS!
}

get_random_color();
```

What am I doing wrong... missing a string to integer conversion to facilitate the math?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in an online compiler. I am not sure If you made spelling mistake while copying code to StackOverFlow but it's parseInt() not parseINT().

```
var ranking = 10
rating_factor = ((parseInt(ranking) / 25)*100).toString() +"%"
console.log('hsl(189, 100%, ' + rating_factor +')'); //OUTPUT: hsl(189, 100%, 40%)
```

This worked for me.

**EDIT** You missed to multiply result with 100 to convert it into percentage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My problem is definitely solved.

Answer (score 0):

As Surya K point out that the function should named [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Another thing is, you can separate mathematics and string manipulation by using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It makes your code clean.

```js
document.getElementById('rating')
  .addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    // obtian user rating form textbox
    var rating = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);
    // calculate the lightness 
    var lightness = rating / 25;

    // substitute the lightness into hsl() and set it to div background color
    document.getElementById('playerTuple').style.backgroundColor = `hsl(189, 100%, ${lightness}%)`;


  });
```

```css
.playerTuple {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Player Rating :
<input type="text" id="rating" name="rating">

<br>

<div id="playerTuple" class="playerTuple">
  Player Tuple
</div>
```